# Using http based IFRAME in https URL

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have php application in https mode. And the parent(https) contains an iframe. The iframe src will be a http file. The parent and the iframe are in the same domain. But i am not able to access the iframe source using http.

Is there any way in to fix this issue using php or javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is poor security to access http content after initializing https.

Comment: Please clarify, do you mean by JS or html (target)

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this javascript, I assume you mean to access the iframe source using javascript.

Because of the same origin policy in your browser, pages can communicate across different windows or iframes only when their protocols (http vs. https), port, and domain are the same.

Since your protocols are different (http vs. https) you cannot use javascript in your page to access the document in the iframe.

Here is more info about same origin policy:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: There are ways to communicate limited messages across an http/https boundary (for example http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) but in general what you are trying to do should not be attempted.